# Grab data inside code

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

So I have gotten the website source, and now im trying to grab the data inside the  tags. How would I go about doing that. Thanks

For example,

```
<start>value</start>
```

Set a string to value

Comment: Please add a link to the question this pertains to.  On it's own, it is a terrible question without reference.

Comment: This is probably [XML](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml). Are you sure you have the rights to grab the data? If you are unsure, you should ask your lawyer.

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser

Comment: @Ian Thompson: The question you link is about parsing HTML. HTML parsers can parse XML, however, they usually also allow non-wellformed XML and HTML that is years behind the current standard. Just mentioning this, might have performance penalties.

Comment: Yes, generally a WEBSITE source is HTML, not XML. If what the OP wants to pass is XML, then the source is most probably the return result of xmlhttprequest, not a WEBSITE source, which the OP claims "So I have gotten the website source ...". XML is a much easier beast to work with. Personally I use the boost::property_tree which uses RapidXML for it's readxml() and writexml() functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XML parser library. Here is a link to one such library: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/

Answer (score 1):

http://expat.sourceforge.net/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx two more alternatives apart from http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/ as mentioned by mtahmed. There are plenty more. Please compare them based on your requirement.